# ReferenceError: React is not defined wix navigation react-native

Tags: react-native, redux, wix-react-native-navigation

When trying to register a screen wrapped with providers in wix react-native-navigation it shows React is not defined in chrome console and the screen dosent load it stays white. I am using RN 0.63.4 and RNN 7.8.3

```
    Navigation.registerComponent(
    Screens.Login,
    () => (props) => (
        <Provider store={store}>
            <Login {...props} />
        </Provider>
    ),
    () => Login
)
```

Comment: Insert your code.

Comment: Did you try @Alvaro Roman 's answer?

Answer (score 1):

Just add `import React from 'react'` at the top! That did it for me.